# regex to match a string start with a word and end with or without number

Tags: regex, powershell, active-directory

I want to use powershell to search all AD samaccountname start with "jamec" - short form of full name like "Jame Cameron" - and end with number but not include other short form like "jamech"

"jamec" - match
"jamec1234" - match
"jamec12" - match

"jamech" - not match
"jamech12" - not match

tried this "^jamec(\d+)(?!.*\d)" but string without number "jamec" become not match.

Comment: Do you mean `^jamec\d*\b`  See https://regex101.com/r/zAbVu8/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
^jamec\d*$
```

This matches `jamec` followed optionally by only one or more digits.  If you want to also match other content in the input, then use `^jamec\d*\b` instead.

If you want to ensure that the first digit in the optional number does not start with zero, then use:

```
^jamec(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?$
```

### Demo

Comment: one more case should not be match, the number start with 0, jamec01. Could you please help

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you tried `^jamec(\d+)(?!.*\d)` requires that there is at least 1 digit following jamec.

The negative lookahead `(?!.*\d)` asserts that in all the characters to the right there can not be a digit present.

---

You could use a word boundary `\b` and match the digits 0+ times using `*` instead of `+`

```
^jamec\d*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5zaJcG/1)

To match nothing after the digits, you could also assert a whitespace boundary

```
^jamec\d*(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hUjIkt/1)